# Is scope.$parent.$emit() a good pratice to emit a event to parent scope ONLY?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why I use `scope.$parent().$emit()` other than `scope.$emit()` is when the directive use `scope:true` and there's one more directive use `scope:true`, and they are placed at same DOM node.

Then `scope.$emit()` will emit event to the other directive too and can be catch as same as parent scope. But `scope.$parent().$emit()` will only emit event to parent. Is it good to use `scope.$parent().$emit()`?

It seems not matter whether other directives can catch the event or not, but I'm not sure about this.So maybe **ONLY** emit to parent can be good at some case.
Here's a example [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MlsOkwcrrHc2fnvZrWPI?p=preview)

"second-directive" event can only be catch by MainCtrl. but "second-directive-two" can be catch by MainCtrl and first directive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is related question: [How to stop $broadcast events in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420765/how-to-stop-broadcast-events-in-angularjs)

You can use

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('second-directive-two', 'from second');
```

instead of

```
$scope.$parent().$emit('second-directive-two', 'from second');
```

and cancel event handling in controller

```
$scope.$on('second-directive-two',function(event,args){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And don't handle event 'second-directive-two' in `first` directive if event has been prevented

```
$scope.$on('second-directive-two',function(event,args){
    if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
        // do useful job
    }
});
```

Here is [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qsKR8GHVIjYpPqWYqyoY?p=preview)

**Update:**

Why it isn't good practice ?

In this case you are tied to structure of DOM hierarchy. Imagine that you have to move directive `First` to partial and include it via `ng-include`. Scope hierarchy has been changed. `$scope.$parent().$emit()` doesn't work since this moment. And you spent time to fix this problem.

Generally `$scope.$parent().$emit()` generate potentially problem code

Comment: this seems good. But I'll appreciate if you can explain why use `$scope.$parent().$emit()` is not good. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you could use [`scope.$broadcast()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) instead of emit. It is like `emit` but the data bubbles the other way around in the scope chain.

Comment: Is $broadcast only broadcast downstream to child scope only? How child scope can use broadcast to broadcast event to parent scope?

Comment: I test it. And using `scope.$broadcast()` can be catch by directive only.