# How to stop $broadcast events from PROPAGATING down the scope chain?

Tags: angularjs

I have seen similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15420765) , But they are dealt by marking the event with `defaultPrevented:yes` to tell the children not to process the event.Is there any way we can stop the propagation of the event down the scope hierarchy?

My scenario is that the controller broadcasting the event have many child scopes out of which only the first child scope needs the event.So taking performance it to consideration i was trying to stop the event propagation at the first level itself.The scenario is illustrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/pko2fudL/1/)

Is that possible?

Comment: This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420765/how-to-stop-broadcast-events-in-angularjs

Comment: @devqon that's the same question OP already linked to

Comment: whoops, googled to fast :)

Comment: Please show some code so we can see what you are working with

Comment: @charlietfl Does the code really matter on this scenario?

Comment: it sure helps if you are wanting workarounds

Comment: @charlietfl i have updated the question with a fiddle.

Comment: I would be wary of premature optimization: how much time does this propagation actually take in your real app? Do other things take longer (e.g. watchers in e digest cycle)?

Comment: If you just want to handle the event in one place would it be easier just to remove the listener on the other scopes?

Comment: Have you shown that performance is actually an issue in this scenario?

Comment: I found a good explanation for your requirements here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898296/how-to-unsubscribe-to-a-broadcast-event-in-angularjs-how-to-remove-function-reg

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent a $broadcast from propagating down the child scopes. instead you can use **event.preventDefault()** in child controller listeners to let them ignore this broadcast event.